# How would I solve the following question on sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recursion

> **Problem 7.** Let $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=0}$ be the sequence defined recursively by $a_{n+3} = 6a_{n+2} - 11a_{n+1} + 6a_n$ for all $n \ge 0$, and such that $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, and $a_3 = 1$. Find a closed form (i.e. non-recursive) expression for $a_n$.

I think it should be rewritten as $x^3 = 6x^2-11x+6$, but I am not sure how to apply $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$. And so, I'm not sure how to find the closed form expression.

Any help?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Problem 7}$

Let $a_n:=x^n$

$$x^{n+3}-6x^{n+2}+11x^{n+1}-6x^{n}=0,$$

divide by $x^{n}$ to get

$$x^3-6x^2+11x-6=0,$$

doing the appropriate algebraic divisions yield

$$(x-3)(x-1)(x-2)=0 \Rightarrow x=\{3,1,2\}.$$

Then our general solution is of the form

$$a_n=A3^n+B+C2^n,$$

where $A,B,C$ are constants that we will find using the initial values.

For $a_1=1$ we have

$$1=3A+B+2C,$$

for $a_2=2$ we have

$$2=9A+B+4C,$$

and for $a_3=3$  we have

$$3=27A+B+8C.$$

Using your favourite method of solving linear systems, you should get (check!)

$$A=-\frac{1}{6}, B=-\frac{1}{2}, C=1.$$

Thus, the solution is

$$a_n=-\frac{1}{6}(3^n)-\frac{1}{2}+2^n.$$